# Trigger row specific kendo ui angular 2 grid mouse over event

Tags: javascript, angular, kendo-grid, mouseover, kendo-ui-angular2

I know that using the template syntax I could use the standard angular 2 (mouseover) event listener to listen for a mouse over event for a specific column. I was wondering if there is a way to listen for mouseover events for an entire row and be able to get the index for that row.

I am trying to a achieve an mouse over hover action the triggers on one row at a time, without having to use multiple `<template>` tags on each column.

Any help is much appreciated. If there is a better approach then I am all ears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to handle the row mouse events from within the 'consuming' component. You should check following GH issue for a runnable sample of such approach: https://github.com/telerik/kendo-angular2/issues/21#issuecomment-247941402